# androit text view Mysql

Tags: android, mysql

Hello I am developing an application android, I have a problem with a text view that retrieves the data via web service, the data retrieve appears but infringe on the other text view of the page, Here is my code from my xml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Détail de l'établissement"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="Libelle :"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvd"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Code postal :"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Ville :"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvl"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="libelle"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvl"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvl"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:hint="Code postal"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvv"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvcp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvcp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:hint="Ville"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Matériel numérique associé"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:text="Présentation" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvv"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvv"
    android:hint="Presentation"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Then my code that says or go data :

```
public class DetailEtab extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.etabdetail);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvl);
        tv.setText(search_ville.etabSELECT.getLibelle());

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcp);
        tv.setText(search_ville.etabSELECT.getCp());

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvv);
        tv.setText(search_ville.etabSELECT.getVille());

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvp);
        tv.setText(search_ville.etabSELECT.getPresentation());


        Button btnSa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMa);
        btnSa.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DetailEtab.this, MaterielAssocie.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.i("ETAB", "servcies associes");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "services associes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If anyone can tell me why it does that thanks

[screenshot][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImHxk.png

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, please?

Comment: Yes i added it .

Comment: Can you also post the full xml  file?

Comment: il est complet , il manque juste la balise </RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems with your layouts. I recommend you to wrap every line into separate LinearLayout and then use LinearLayout to wrap all new LinearLayouts. Also due to long text it's better to wrap parent LinearLayout into Scroll.
**NOTE: This is just example that was written inside text box that simply shows main idea and may contain mistakes**
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Détail de l'établissement"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="Libelle :"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="libelle"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Code postal :"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Code postal"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text="Ville :"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Ville"
    android:textSize="20dp" />    

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:text="Présentation" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Presentation"
    android:textSize="20dp" /> 
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Matériel numérique associé"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: merci c'est déja mieux , j'ai juste a bien tout mettre en face maintenat .

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning tv to multiple different TextViews and then you are assigning multiple values to the last TextView you assign it to.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DetailEtab extends Activity {
    private TextView tv,tv1,tv2,tv3;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.etabdetail);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvl);
        tv.setText(search_ville.etabSELECT.getLibelle());

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvcp);
        tv1.setText(search_ville.etabSELECT.getCp());

        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvv);
        tv2.setText(search_ville.etabSELECT.getVille());

        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvp);
        tv3.setText(search_ville.etabSELECT.getPresentation());


        Button btnSa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMa);
        btnSa.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DetailEtab.this, MaterielAssocie.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.i("ETAB", "servcies associes");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "services associes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: always same and no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Détail de l'établissement"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvd"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="Libelle :"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Code postal :"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Ville :"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvl"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="hfdgsjfhgadsjfgajsdfhgggdsjfgsdjafhgjsdafhgjdhfgjsdhgfjdshfgjdshfgjhdgfjdshgfjhdgfjsdhgafjahgsdfjdshgfjhdsagfjhdsgafjhsdagfjhdsgafjhsadgfjfdgjshfgjhfgjhsdgfhsgdfjhdsgfjhgdsjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjhfgjsdhgfjsdhgfjsdhfgjsdhfgjdsfhgjsdhgfjdshgfjsdhgfjhsgdfjhsdgjfhdgfjhgdsf"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:hint="libelle"
        android:textSize="20dp"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvcp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvl"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvl"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:hint="Code postal"
        android:text="hfdgsjfhgadsjfgajsdfhgggdsjfgsdjafhgjsdafhgjdhfgjsdhgfjdshfgjdshfgjhdgfjdshgfjhdgfjsdhgafjahgsdfjdshgfjhdsagfjhdsgafjhsdagfjhdsgafjhsadgfjfdgjshfgjhfgjhsdgfhsgdfjhdsgfjhgdsjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjhfgjsdhgfjsdhgfjsdhfgjsdhfgjdsfhgjsdhgfjdshgfjsdhgfjhsgdfjhsdgjfhdgfjhgdsf"

        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvv"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvcp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvcp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="hfdgsjfhgadsjfgajsdfhgggdsjfgsdjafhgjsdafhgjdhfgjsdhgfjdshfgjdshfgjhdgfjdshgfjhdgfjsdhgafjahgsdfjdshgfjhdsagfjhdsgafjhsdagfjhdsgafjhsadgfjfdgjshfgjhfgjhsdgfhsgdfjhdsgfjhgdsjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjhfgjsdhgfjsdhgfjsdhfgjsdhfgjdsfhgjsdhgfjdshgfjsdhgfjhsgdfjhsdgjfhdgfjhgdsf"

        android:hint="Ville"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Matériel numérique associé"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="Présentation"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvv"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvv"
        android:text="hfdgsjfhgadsjfgajsdfhgggdsjfgsdjafhgjsdafhgjdhfgjsdhgfjdshfgjdshfgjhdgfjdshgfjhdgfjsdhgafjahgsdfjdshgfjhdsagfjhdsgafjhsdagfjhdsgafjhsadgfjfdgjshfgjhfgjhsdgfhsgdfjhdsgfjhgdsjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjfhgsdjhfgjsdhgfjsdhgfjsdhfgjsdhfgjdsfhgjsdhgfjdshgfjsdhgfjhsgdfjhsdgjfhdgfjhgdsf"
        android:hint="Presentation"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```